# Getting websocket error code 1006 when trying to connect to Actioncable server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, nativescript, error-code, actioncable

I'm building an app using Nativescript/Angular 2 and I'm also using a javascript [library](https://github.com/sacketty/nativescript-actioncable) to use websockets connecting it with an Actioncable Rails app.
When trying to establish connection I get a websocket error code 1006 on the Nativescript log console and the connection gets closed.

I noticed that the initial HTTP (the handshake) request sends two values for Sec-WebSocket-Protocol on the header (actioncable-v1-json, actioncable-unsupported) but the headers in the response have only one value for Sec-WebSocket-Protocol which is 'actioncable-v1-json' and 'actioncable-unsupported' is missing.

I believe this error happens because of the missing protocol in the response.
Does anyone know how to add this header (actioncable-unsupported) to the handshake response? Or any other ideas of what is causing this error?

There is no error in the rails log, it just gets connected and then disconnected:

```
Started GET "/v1/cable/" [WebSocket] for 192.168.1.8 at 2017-04-02 17:04:06 -0700
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
Finished "/v1/cable/" [WebSocket] for 192.168.1.8 at 2017-04-02 17:04:06 -0700
```

The error message displayed on the Nativescript console is this:

```
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-actioncable/lib/action_cable.js:46:33: [ActionCable] Opening WebSocket, current state is null, subprotocols: actioncable-v1-json,actioncable-unsupported 1491179483038
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-actioncable/lib/action_cable.js:46:33: [ActionCable] ConnectionMonitor started. pollInterval = 3000 ms 1491179483042
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-actioncable/lib/action_cable.js:46:33: [ActionCable] Socket was closed because:    code:  1006 1491179483109
```

Thank you

Comment: any luck regarding this ?

Comment: No, I ended up switching to Socket-io. Now it works fine with it.

Comment: socket-io client with Actioncable on server ?

Comment: I've got same error since I forgot to launch redis server.
Action Cable uses redis by default in production. check config/cable.yml.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue and the issue was the cable.yml configuration.

We noticed that the staging environment had this value for url:

```
url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/1" } %>
```

Removing that value and actually other values fixed it for us.

New cable.yml staging config:

```
staging:
  adapter: redis
```

Working!